# Trigger a behavior from another module in Javascript?

Tags: 8, javascript

The block_ajax module defines a behavior in its module:

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/block_ajax/-/blob/8.x-1.x/js/refresh_ajax_block_command.js

I want to initiate this call every 60 seconds so the contents of the block can refresh if there is new data from my own script file.

I tried two ways.

The first way I tried was setting up a route for a simple controller that returned an AjaxResponse:

```
  public function execute() {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new RefreshBlockAjaxCommand('.my_block'));
    return $response;
  }
```

Hitting the route with `Drupal.ajax` results in 'context.querySelectorAll is not a function', but it appears that the block *is* replaced (but missing the block wrapper around it, oddly enough, which probably won't work calling it over and over).

The second way is I tried to call it from the [browser console with Javascript](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107909/call-a-drupal-behavior-method-from-inside-another-behavior), but I can't figure out between this answer and the linked Javascript file at the top of the question what to call.

Trying to loop the element and attachBehaviors results in this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a couple of things.

One, I was getting the querySelectorAll error because the Block being rendered was being rendered with a theme and custom template file, which was missing an outer div. The first tag it was seeing was a `<style>` tag, and breaking on that.

Second, the block_ajax module seems buggy and not fit for refreshing on intervals.

I wound up removing the library that module attaches (from the original question), copying that, and attaching that to my block with two key changes:

Instead of `.replaceWith` I use `.html` to preserve the outer Block tags (or they get lost, and the next Ajax command will fail):

```
// Compose a new block content, replacing the old one
// with it.
var $newBlock = $(data.content);
$block.html($newBlock);
```

Then, I added this to the file, to initiate a check every 30 seconds with Ajax:

```
  // Check every 30 seconds if there is a notification.
  setInterval(refresh, 30000);

  function refresh() {
    Drupal.ajax({url: '/api/v1/auth/refresh'}).execute();
  }
```

Which uses the same service that the block does to read/check an external service for auth state and cookie updates.

Wanted to note that various forms of `Drupal.attachBehaviors(context, drupalSettings);` did not seem to do anything at all. Perhaps its something wrong in the block_ajax module. It was not returning any errors, but also not refreshing the display.

Comment: "Instead of .replaceWith I use .html to preserve the outer Block tags (or they get lost, and the next Ajax command will fail):" Thanks, this was the key. I've opened an issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/block_ajax/issues/3351439

Answer (score 0):

> Hitting the route with Drupal.ajax results in
>   'context.querySelectorAll is not a function.

This happens when Drupal.attachBehaviors() is passed a jQuery object. It expects an HTML string. So if you are doing this:

```
var element = $(".some_element");
Drupal.attachBehaviors(element);
```

You change it to:

```
$(".some_element").each(function () {
  Drupal.attachBehaviors($(this).eq(0));
});
```

Comment: Just tried that, I still get `Uncaught TypeError: context.querySelectorAll is not a function`

Comment: Doing this does in the console does not throw an error, but the AJAX doesn't fire: `Drupal.attachBehaviors(element.get(0), drupalSettings)`

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'ajax doesn't fire', but this will not prevent ajax from firing.

Comment: It does not trigger the events of this other modules defined behavior: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/block_ajax/-/blob/8.x-1.x/js/refresh_ajax_block_command.js  - no network activity or anything. Essentially I want this block to be refreshed every 60 seconds, instead of once per page load.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the correct element? Run console.log() on `element.get(0)` and see if the elements that are supposed to have the ajax attached are contained in the returned value.

Comment: They are, but there are two, not one (the other shows up for mobile I believe). element.get(0) returns the entire block html as a string.

Comment: Then you need to loop through the elements. I've updated my code accordingly.

Comment: Attaching a screenshot of what happens to the question.

Comment: I've updated the code.